# Get RGB values from NSCustomColorSpace (10.13 breaks NSColorList?)

Tags: cocoa

Since 10.13 the colors from NSColorList are in NSCustomColorSpace and my old function to return RGB values started failing.

How should I get the RGBA components from the color now since NSColor methods don't work in this color space? CGColorGetComponents works and returns 4 components (RGBA) so I just assume use that but what does Apple want us to do now that they broke NSColor for NSColorList.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround/solution for this?  I'm having similar problem now in Mojave beta.